# What is the purpose of NSNotification

Tags: iphone

i am new Notification.what is the purpose of it...
can we use  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver without postNotification,
If we can do it,how it is identified?what is the relationship between addObserver and postNotification?any one can explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

it's rather straight forward: you define an event by giving it a unique name, then you add an observer to it using `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver` and point it to a selector that receives the event.

then later on in your code you can `postNotification` and if the unique name matches the one you registered for - the selector you provided will be called.

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver is one view controller....postnotifaction and selector method is in one view controller..will it work?

Comment: Absolutely. defaultCenter is shared for the whole application.